# What can i do to made "Rock, papper, scissors" work?

Tags: javascript

i'm very new to js, and it's my first code on it. i'm trying to make a game "rock, papper, scissors". please, look at my code, my funcrion playRound doesn't wor, i need it to return scores.
please, give me advises how to change my code, but i don't want you to solve all for me. thank you.

```js
function computerPlay() {
    let computerAction = Math.floor(Math.random() * choises.length);
    let computerSelection = choises[computerAction];
    return computerSelection;
}

function userPlay() {
    let playerSelection = prompt(choises).toLowerCase();
    return playerSelection;
}

let choises = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

let Score = new Map([
    ['userScores', 0],
    ['computerScores', 0]
]);


function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (playerSelection === choises[0] && computerSelection === choises[0]) ||
    (playerSelection === choises[1] && computerSelection === choises[1]) ||
    (playerSelection === choises[2] && computerSelection === choises[2]){
        return Score = ['userScores' + 1, 'computerScores' + 1];
    } else if (playerSelection === choises[0] && computerSelection !== choises[0]) ||
    (playerSelection === choises[1] && computerSelection !== choises[1]) ||
    (playerSelection === choises[2] && computerSelection !== choises[2])
        return Score = ['userScores' + 1, 'computerScores'];
    } else if (playerSelection !== choises[0] && computerSelection === choises[0]) ||
    (playerSelection !== choises[1] && computerSelection === choises[1]) ||
    (playerSelection !== choises[2] && computerSelection === choises[2])
    {
        return Score = ['userScores', 'computerScores' + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (playerSelection === choises[0] && computerSelection === choises[0]) ||` you need more `(` and `)`. Check the if condition syntax

Comment: call `playRound()` without parameters, and set them withing the function, using: `playerSelection=userPlay()` and `computerSelection=computerPlay()` first things in the function.  btw, "choises" is spelled "choices" - not that it matters to javascript/computer... :)

Comment: also, something is wrong with map and scores...  see @bravemaster's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to this:

```js
function computerPlay() {
    let computerAction = Math.floor(Math.random() * choises.length);
    let computerSelection = choises[computerAction];
    return computerSelection;
}

function userPlay() {
    let playerSelection = prompt(choises).toLowerCase();
    return playerSelection;
}

let choises = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

let Score = {
    user: 0,
    computer: 0
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (playerSelection === computerSelection){
        Score.user = Score.user + 1;
        Score.computer = Score.computer + 1;
    } else if ((playerSelection === choises[0] && computerSelection === choises[2]) ||
    (playerSelection === choises[1] && computerSelection === choises[0]) ||
    (playerSelection === choises[2] && computerSelection === choises[1])) {
        Score.user = Score.user + 1;
    } else {
        Score.computer = Score.computer + 1;
    }
}

let computerChoice = computerPlay();
let userChoice = userPlay();
playRound(userChoice, computerChoice);
console.log('computer hand', computerChoice);
console.log('user hand', userChoice);
console.log(Score);
```